# Bad override class name for this key. Please update class_name field

Tags: prestashop

I'm using prestashop 1.4

I get the following error in the webservice api

> Bad override class name for this key. Please update class_name field

This didn't happened before on similar installation.

I notice the line:

```
        if ($bad_class_name) {

            $this->setError(500, 'Bad override class name for this key. Please update class_name field', 126);
        }
```

when I comment this line, it seems to work (though the full loop still fails).

The bad_class_name is passed to the fetch method.

but why?

Answer (score 0):

this is a result of wrong username (user key)

in chrome - 
add username@ at the begining of the url to relogin - e.g. username@localhost/api